# mysql Does the change in where clause order of select query increases performace?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Is there any performance benefit if order of where clause criteria changes ?

what i mean is e.g.

i have a select query,

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE enabled = '1' AND type = 'pictures' AND category = 'family'
```

now in above query

1. enabled comes first and in my table there are 95% rows are enabled .
2. type comes  second where my table contains 75% rows which are of
   type pictures
3. category comes last where my table contains 20% rows which
   are in family category.

so my question is 
will i see any perfomance benefit if i order the where clause like this

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE category = 'family' AND type = 'pictures' AND enabled = '1'
```

Thanks
using : MYISAM as table engine.
and all the columns in where clause has index .

Comment: Do you have a single index on your 3 columns ? Or you have created 3 indexes (one per column) ?

Comment: 3  indexes , 1 per column as 3 columns are optional depending on the query . like some queries may contains only types and some may contains only enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nah, the optimizer is clever enough to use the best index in this simple `SELECT`.. use an `EXPLAIN` on each to double check if you like (they should come out the same).

You may get better performance if you add one INDEX on all three columns however.

Comment: you mean an additional index keepeing already created index or only one including the 3 columns ?

Comment: I agree, but it depends on MySQL version, new versions can handle multiple indexes. If you use one Index, be careful cause the order will matter.

Comment: but 3 columns are optional depending on the query . like some queries may contains only types and some may contains only enabled.so making new will help.

Comment: you said "You may get better performance if you add one INDEX on all three columns" do i have to preserve the order too ? which  used while creating index ? thanks

Comment: Sidenote: In `WHERE` the order is not important. But important is the order of tables you `JOIN`.

Comment: @AMB If you need the individual indexes keep them but you could try creating an index on all 3 columns for queries that require all three (or more). This will slow down your INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE queries though. You can always check which index is used in a SELECT with EXPLAIN.

Comment: @DanFromGermany thanks, not joining any tables , just single table query.

Comment: @Arth the above posted is just a sample query and there are 3-4 optional fields , so do i have to create the maximum possible indexes ? or only one contains all fields , e.g. one query may contains only field1 and field3 while another query may contain field2 and field3.

Comment: @AMB In effect the data is concatenated in a composite index in the order of it's columns, thus an index (a,b,c) could be used by `WHERE a=x` and  `WHERE a=x AND b=y AND c=z` but not `WHERE b=y AND c=z` or `WHERE a=z AND c=z`. [**More info**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: @Arth thats deep, so gotta create specific column index and multiple column indexes keeping each column/field as first, will try with the explain command more..,

Comment: @AMB Yep, indexes are a bit of a dark art.. getting the optimizer to use the right one is also tricky! You can get some outrageous performance benefits if you get it right however!